# How to replace NULL values with other rows in the same group of ID with a set of conditions

Tags: sql, ssms

I have a table A where I need to replace *Customer* **NULL** values with either one of the other possible values (222,333) that have the same *PersonID_map* (1). The *customer* id chosen depends on condition such as

- If only one is active chose that.
- Else if, both are class 'E' chose any
- Else chose H

Table A:

| Memberno | Personid | PersonID_map | RelationshipID | Customer | Active | Class |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 222 | 1 | 1 | Membr | 222 | A | H |
| 333 | 123 | 1 | Membr | 333 | A | E |
| 19 | 1 | 1 | Non-Membr | NULL | A | E |
| 444 | 321 | 2 | Membr | 444 | A | E |
| 555 | 1231 | 2 | Membr | 555 | T | H |
| 666 | 2 | 2 | Non-Membr | NULL | A | H |

It should look something like:

| Memberno | Personid | PersonID_map | RelationshipID | Customer | Active | Class |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 222 | 1 | 1 | Membr | 222 | A | H |
| 333 | 123 | 1 | Membr | 333 | A | E |
| 19 | 1 | 1 | Non-Membr | 222 | A | E |
| 444 | 321 | 2 | Membr | 444 | A | E |
| 555 | 1231 | 2 | Membr | 555 | T | H |
| 666 | 2 | 2 | Non-Membr | 444 | A | H |

Comment: SSMS is just an IDE-like application that is used with several products such as (but not limited to) SQL Server, Azure SQL Edge and Azure Synapse. SSMS is likely irrelevant to the question here. What product are you actually using for your data engine? Tagging [[tag:SSMS]] for your data engine is like tagging [[tag:visual-studio]] for your programming language; it doesn't actually really tell us anything.